# matplotlib Python scrolling through slices

Tags: python, medical

I am trying to read the brain MRI image in to the plot and scroll trough the image slices.I can read the image however I cant find a way to show all the slices of the brain. The image is mha format. Could anyone suggest what should be used to to this?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28yu3.png)

```
import SimpleITK
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filenameT1 = "12.mha"
idxSlice = 98
labelGrayMatter = 1
imgT1Original = SimpleITK.ReadImage(filenameT1)


def sitk_show(img, title=None, margin=0.0, dpi=40):
    nda = SimpleITK.GetArrayFromImage(img)
    figsize = (1 + margin) * nda.shape[0] / dpi, (1 + margin) * 
    nda.shape[1] / dpi
    extent = (0, nda.shape[1], nda.shape[0], 0)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)
    ax = fig.add_axes([margin, margin, 1 - 2 * margin, 1 - 2 * margin])

plt.set_cmap("gray")
ax.imshow(nda, extent=extent, interpolation=None)

def onscroll(self, event):
    print("%s %s" % (event.button, event.step))
    if event.button == 'up':
        self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % self.slices
    else:
        self.ind = (self.ind - 1) % self.slices
    self.update()

def update(self):
    self.im.set_data(self.imgT1Original[:, :, self.ind])
    ax.set_ylabel('slice %s' % self.ind)
    self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()


if title:
    plt.title(title)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', sitk_show.onscroll)
plt.show()
sitk_show(SimpleITK.Tile(imgT1Original[:, :, idxSlice],(2, 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Can you illustrate an attempt you've made (with code) and maybe speculate about why it didn't work? :p

Comment: I edited the code i am trying to add on scroll event, i think thats the way to go here. However i have no experience in working with matplotlib, never had to do such a thing before. I think maybe its the way im reading the image with SimpleITK maybe this is not possible with imshow()?